# why /usr/local/bin/pm2 symlink to pm2-runtime when install pm2?

Tags: pm2

When I install pm2 on Linux like this:

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

`usr/local/bin/pm2` links to `$installDir/pm2/bin/pm2-runtime`.

But if I install the same version of pm2 on MacOS like this:

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

`~/npm/bin/pm2` links to `$installDir/pm2/bin/pm2`.

What happened when install the same package on different OS platform?

Comment: what is the issue that you need help with?

Comment: please specify the desired behaviour or a problem. "What happened" is not a very constructive question